# How to download owncloud app which is not approved?

Tags: owncloud

Maybe that's a stupid question, but how do I download an owncloud app which is not approved yet?
Precisely, I want to test this:

http://apps.owncloud.com/content/show.php/AppVNCZimbra?content=155100

and it says there were already 661 downloads but I cannot find a download link nor any information on the owncloud website how to download it or why I cannot download it. There is one post in their forum of a guy asking the same question a few months ago but no one answered.
The app is under review for days and who knows how long the review might take.

Answer (score 0):

An ownCloud app currently marked as "nor approved" is in review process stage. That probably means it could be downloaded before, but some details was changed (most likely an update). Because of this change the app has to be reviewed again to make sure no backdoors or security problems were introduced with the update. 
During the review process only members of ownclouds review team can access the app. As soon as it has been approved you will see the download link again.